# Can't access my gmail smtp client with an app password in php

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

So, I use phpMailer to send mails throught gmail's smtp, here is my code

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor\autoload.php';
define('GMailUSER', 'gigabattleboard@gmail.com');
define('GMailPWD', '****************');
function smtpMailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) {
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
  );
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->Username = GMailUser;
  $mail->Password = GMailPWD;
  $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->Body = $body;
  $mail->AddAddress($to);
  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    return 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

$result = smtpmailer('fainfutia@mail.com', 'gigabattleboard@mail.com', 'Giga Battleboard', 'Message', 'Subject');
  if (true !== $result)
{
  echo $result;
}
```

I created an app password on the google account I use, after having activated the two-factor verification. But I still get the same error:

> 2023-01-13 14:21:05 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s23-20020a1cf217000000b003d1e3b1624dsm29449744wmc.2 - gsmtp
> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Unfortunately, the link given by the error did not bring me anything conclusive.
How do I get out of this?

Comment: @DalmTo posted a good answer, but there are two other things that do not help: do not disable certificate verification (see the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide for why), and `SMTPDebug = 1` is useless for debugging server issues; use 2or 3. The first place you should look for answers when you’re having trouble with a package is always the package docs. Everything you’ve asked here is answered in the PHPMailer docs, which would have been much faster for you than writing this question and waiting for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apps password needs to be use in your code in place of your actual google password.  If you are still seeing `Username and Password not accepted`. then you have not used the apps password in your code.

```
$mail->Username = GMailUser;
$mail->Password = AppsPassWord;
```

- [Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)
- [How to create a Apps Password for connecting to Google's SMTP server.](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IGOt3zo98Xw)

If that doesn't work let me know I should have a PHP sample floating around.

## Your code runs fine with an apps password

I just ran your code. The only thing i changed was fixing the constant and setting the from to that of the constant rather then hard coding your email address.    It runs fine

```
<?php

// Run composer require phpmailer/phpmailer

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor\autoload.php';

const GMailUSEREmail = 'MyEmailAddress';
const GoogleAppsPassword = 'MyAppsPassword';

function smtpMailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body): bool|string
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = GMailUSEREmail;
    $mail->Password = GoogleAppsPassword;
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        return 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

$result = smtpmailer(GMailUSEREmail, GMailUSEREmail, 'Giga Battleboard', 'Message', 'Subject');
if (true !== $result)
{
    echo $result;
}
```

The email sent

[image]

Comment: That's what I did, I said it in the post, it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: if you had it would fix it you have done something wrong watch my video I show you how.  I can do another video in php next week if you really need

Comment: I insist, that's exactly what I did, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Login to 'gigabattleboard@gmail.com' and go to the google account.  Under security you will find where you can create an apps password.  https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IGOt3zo98Xw

Comment: I ran your code with my email and my apps password it does work.

Comment: I insist again, that I did that, and it doesn't work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nw-AYeEdOw

Comment: For the fun of it print out what GMailUSER says.   It may be your define thats the only thing i changed.  or try it locally maybe your not uploading the file to your server that you have changed maybe its an old file on your server.

Comment: Okay, so, I reinstalled phpmailer, and ran your code after changing some things in it, and it works. I have no ideas what made it work, and why it didn't before.
Thank you a lot though. ^^